# How to des_encrypt all my mysql table data by command prompt?

Tags: mysql, database, encryption, command-line

Is it possible to update all MySQL database tables, so that all data are encrypted, using the command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is an option by MySQl to encrypt the data files but already there is a question similar to this,,
Check that out,,

http://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143750/mysql-and-data-file-encryption