# Protect database with password like Microsoft Access

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, encryption, password-protection

I want to ask for something in Database protection.

I have a Windows Application that will be deployed to different clients, while deploying i am creating a database on client machine.

The Question here is can i protect this database with password so, ONLY my application can access it.

The database engine may be Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that you mean by 'password protecting your database'? Have your application for user login. Then password they type should match with the one you are sending in the `connection` string to the database. Voila ;) let us know if you have further queries. Happy to help.

Comment: I want to my database to be protected with some technique, so that user who has administrator privileges cannot access my database, the only one can access the database is my application

Answer (score 0):

You [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) access to a MySQL database and/or table to a user with an optional password. When you want to access this database, you must provide the user and password.

But there's no automatic encryption. You might want to look at this question [MySQL and data file encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/143750/1741542) and it's answers.

For security related questions, you might also look into [Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/security.html) and [Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html).

Comment: In this solution what about the MySql Server DBA, or the user has administrator privileges ?

Comment: @AbdullahDarwish When you look at the manual, there are several privileges, you can grant to a user, ranging from simple select, insert, delete and more dangerous like alter or drop tables.

Comment: this not my question, my question if i created user and grant permission what about the user who have the root password for mysql server can he access my database or not ?

Comment: @AbdullahDarwish Yes, the user with the password for the database administrator can always access your database. But you can give the MySQL database administrator a password different from the root user of the windows machine. See [Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking this because want to prevent someone from knowing your data structures or internal data storage, but you cannot do that to a user with DBA privileges on SQL server or any other real database.

If you really want to hide that from your customers (which is not a good idea for me), you may evaluate installing it in a server which is also physically and logically under your control. Nowadays, a good solution for this may be hosting this server in the cloud, for example hosting your data in AZURE.

Hiding your database structures doesn't look professional to me.